# python-CSV Multiple Columns with the same header into one column

Tags: python, pandas, stack

I have a CSV file with company data with 22 rows and 6500 columns. The columns have the same names and I should get the columns with the same names stacked into individual columns according to their headers.

I have now the data in one df like this:

```
Y   C   Y   C   Y   C

1.  a   1.  b.  1.  c.

2.  a.  2.  b.  2.  c.
```

and I need to get it like this:

```
Y   C

1.  a. 

2.  a. 

1.  b.

2.  b.

1.  c.

2.  c.
```

Comment: Can you provide any minimal reproducible example and a desired output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try an attempt where you slice the df in chunks by iteration and concat them back together, since the column names can't be identified distinctly.

**EDIT**
Changed answer to new input:

```
chunksize = 2
df = (
    pd.concat(
        [
            df.iloc[:, i:i+chunksize] for i in range(0, len(df.columns), chunksize)
        ]
    )
    .reset_index(drop=True))
print(df)
```

```
   Y  C
0  1  a
1  2  a
2  1  b
3  2  b
4  1  c
5  2  c
```

Comment: This stacks the columns but leaves the "old" columns in the data frame

Comment: yes, the result is in `stacked_df`. The original dataframe `df` stays untouched. If you don't want that, just change the name from `stacked_df` to `df` and the original df gets overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist looking for a solution.
The best I found so far accounts for the fact that `pd.read_csv` addresses repeated column names by appending '.N' to the duplicates.

```py
In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('duplicate_columns.csv')
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   1  2  3  4 1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 1.2 2.2 3.2 4.2
0  a  q  j  e   w   e   r   t   y   u   d   s
1  b  w  w  f   c   e   f   g   d   c   s   a
2  d  q  e  h   c   f   b   f   a   w   q   r
```

To put your data into the same column...

1. Group the *columns* by their original names.
2. Apply a flattener to convert to a series of arrays.
3. Create a new data frame from the series viewed as a dict.

```py
In [3]: grouper = lambda l: l.split('.')[0]    # peels off added suffix
In [4]: flattener = lambda v: v.stack().values # reshape groups
In [4]: pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(by=grouper, axis='columns')
   ...:                .apply(flattener)
   ...:                .to_dict())
Out[4]:
   1  2  3  4
0  a  q  j  e
1  w  e  r  t
2  y  u  d  s
3  b  w  w  f
4  c  e  f  g
5  d  c  s  a
6  d  q  e  h
7  c  f  b  f
8  a  w  q  r
```

I'd love to see a cleaner, less obtuse, general solution.